# ABCPdf giving "Unable to render HTML. Unable to apply JScript" even with simple OnLoadScript

Tags: c#, javascript, abcpdf

I'm trying to do some simple DOM manipulation when a page is rendered as a PDF using ABCPdf. I followed what they document here: http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf9net/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/2-properties/usescript.htm

But when I try something as simple as the following:

```
var doc = new Doc();
doc.HtmlOptions.UseScript = true;
doc.HtmlOptions.UseNoCache = true;
doc.HtmlOptions.PageCachePurge();
doc.HtmlOptions.OnLoadScript = @"var reportElms = document.getElementsByClassName(""report"");";
doc.Page = doc.AddPage();
doc.AddImageUrl(Url.Action("TestPdf", "Pdf", new { }, "http"));
```

I get the exception:

```
Unable to render HTML. Unable to apply JScript.
COM error 80020101.

Script 'var reportElms = document.getElementsByClassName("report");'.
```

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

<strike>**Not even the built in functions work**</strike>

I'm even getting the same exception with the following script:

```
doc.HtmlOptions.OnLoadScript = @"
    window.ABCpdf_RenderWait(); 
    window.ABCpdf_RenderComplete();";
```

Btw, I'm using version 8 because that's what we have a licence for.

**Edit:**

I was missing the `.external` for the `ABCpdf_RenderWait()` and `ABCpdf_RenderComplete()` calls. It works if you reference them properly (imagine that):

```
doc.HtmlOptions.OnLoadScript = @"
    window.external.ABCpdf_RenderWait(); 
    window.external.ABCpdf_RenderComplete();";
```

Though as I mention in my answer, there are a lot of security hoops that need to be jumped through for IE also.

Comment: Do you use Gecko or IE? Did you try the window.ABCpdf_go example?

Comment: The default is IE and when I tried to switch it complained about a missing Gecko DLL, so I'm just sticking with IE.

Comment: Guess I cannot help you then. I switched to Gecko as I experienced several problems, such as inconsistencies depending on OS/IE. Maybe my posts can help you in any way http://devio.wordpress.com/category/abcpdf/

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't actually get the IE engine to execute JavaScript the way I wanted but I was able to find a solution using the Gecko engine. The original NuGet install did not include the Gecko DLL, so I just downloaded the standalone install and added the DLLs manually.

After that everything worked exactly as expected.

I believe that the IE engine didn't work because it requires a lot of security configuration, because the FAQs spend a lot of time discussing debugging of security: http://www.websupergoo.com/support.htm#6.7